# Set font size with ESC/POS commands?

Tags: c#, printing

I am programming a C# application that sends some printing to a thermal standard printer.

I can control printing with ESC/POS commands, however, I have not found a way to set the character size.

There is a command to set it, but only between 2 values, or it is very small or very big. I need an intermediate value.

This is what I am currently sending to the printer:

```
_sockets[this.IP].Send(new byte[] { 0x1B, (byte)'@',          // Initialize the printer
                                    0x1B, (byte)'J', 30,      // Set printing position (Y)
                                    0x1B, (byte)'!', 1,       // Select character size
                                    0x1B, (byte)'E', 1,       // Bold
                                    0x1B, (byte)'$', 0, 0 }); // Set printing position (X)
```

With `ESC !` command I send, I control the size, however, printing appears very small. If I quadruplicate size, it appears very big.

How can I do it?

Comment: How to print small font in ESC/POS Command ?